# Tikz color opacity spills over to page

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

for some reason, the use of the opacity option in my tikz diagram "spills over" to the rest of the page. Weirder still, this isn't visible from the preview window in texstudio, but it is when opened in acrobat reader.

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=2cm,paperheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document} 
\centering

{\color{blue} text} \pagebreak[4]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[opacity=0.25] (1,0) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

{\color{blue} text} \pagebreak[4]

{\color{blue} text}

\end{document}
```

Previewer:

[image]

Acrobat:

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

pdf [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aJwq1iOz2tUy9FTCwx_49PAa7ofcobdR/view?usp=sharing).

log [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17eSKZDAX9ZV2Jk2cYohp1N4JBYRT0FDl).

---

Update:
So the linked pdf works fine on my computer (at home). The issue might therefore have something to do with acrobat's setup/installation on my work computer - like the deleted comment suggested. Still have no clue what's going on, or indeed how many pdf readers out there might display the glitch.

Comment: No problem here. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @ Ulrike I'm using the latest texstudio release and I believe the binaries were installed with texlive on this machine (at work). I'll check it out on mine tonight and update this post accordingly.

Comment: texstudio is an editor, not a tex system. Show your log-file.

Comment: Can you share the pdf? This way we could test if it is a problem of your pdf viewer or your tex installation. Your code works for me in acrobat. If your pdf would not work for me this would mean a tex problem, if it would work it would be a viewer problem.

Comment: Also no problems here. Note furthermore that blue with 25% opacity should be much lighter than the blue depicted on the second page of the second image (instead it seems to be a blend of a gray and blue). As such, it does not seem like the opacity "spills over", but that something else is going wrong in your pdf viewer.

Comment: Agreed, I used the term "spillover" rather loosely, as it appeared that getting rid of the gradient opacity solved the problem (which I did not show in my post). But even if this is (in part) due to the reader's setup, doesn't the problem suggest that something in tikz (or my tex installation) is causing it?